# Adding a pass with @ and \ characters to define('FTP_PASS' '@Aj\Zx5YJG')

Tags: php, config

i want to add a password to this line :

```
define('FTP_PASS' '@Aj\Zx5YJG')
```

but wp-confing will not recognize @ and \ as characters and for that reason my website goes down.

How can i add those characters as text there?

[image: CHECK IMG]

thanks!

Comment: Have you try with adding ` \ ` before it. `define('FTP_PASS' ,'\@Aj\\Zx5YJG')` ?

Comment: Use escape character \ before your problematic characters

Comment: You should check you error log when u encouter a white screen or enabled error_reporting when so

Comment: Yep, tried. Check photo in updated post.

Comment: Your added screenshot... those quotes don't look standard?

Comment: @Scuzzy can you post that as an answer because i can't vote your comment here. Issue Solved! THANKS!

Comment: @Scuzzy: `those quotes don't look standard` What's the reason. Anyway great eyes... :-). @legacy.so: Whats different in that quote?

Comment: @Scuzzy i copied the code from i file i had used previously but for some reason it used those quotes and not the regular ones. Asap i changed to the regular ones the code it worked perfectly.

Comment: "Whats different in that quote" The curvature, they should be straight up and down `'` vs `‘’` Thats what stood out to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo? you're missing a comma between the two parameters and the quotes on the screenshot do not look regular.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

```
define('FTP_PASS','@Aj\Zx5YJG');
```

Comment: well your right about the comma but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('FTP_PASS' '\@Aj\\Zx5YJG')
```

Escape the characters or use different brackets

Comment: Tried, didn't work.